# Shell : Compressed files as zip without its parent Home directory when unzip

Tags: linux, shell

Assuming i have file structure as below

```
- /home/mm13854/workbook
  -PreBook Balances Summary Sample.twb
  -Rate Trend Sample.twb
  -Tickets Summary Sample.twb
  -Image [ Folder ]
```

I have decalred a variable in my sh file , What this does is that it will zip its parent folder as well . Zip file will contain Home Folder,

```
#variable
TABLEAU_REPORTING_FOLDER=/home/mm13854/workbook

for file in ${TABLEAU_REPORTING_FOLDER}/*.txt; 
do 
zip -r "$file%.twb".zip "$file" ${TABLEAU_REPORTING_FOLDER}/Image; 
done

Output , it will state
adding: home/mm13854/workbook/PreBook Balances Summary Sample.twb (deflated 91%)
adding: home/mm13854/workbook/Image/ (stored 0%)
adding: home/mm13854/workbook/Image/Citilogo_v2.JPG (deflated 84%)
adding: home/mm13854/workbook/Rate Trend Sample.twb (deflated 93%)
adding: home/mm13854/workbook/Image/ (stored 0%)
adding: home/mm13854/workbook/Image/Citilogo_v2.JPG (deflated 84%)
adding: home/mm13854/workbook/Tickets Summary Sample.twb (deflated 92%)
adding: home/mm13854/workbook/Image/ (stored 0%)
adding: home/mm13854/workbook/Image/Citilogo_v2.JPG (deflated 84%)
```

if i unzip the files, it will contain "Home" folder ,
However, if i use the script below , this will work just fine. But i will have to use a cd command to go to its directory before i can use the zip command which is not the ideal approach as this is hard coded. I am trying to avoid using "cd" command and declare the path as a variable .

```
cd home/mm13854/workbook/
for file in *.twb; do zip -r "$file%.twb".zip "$file" Image; done 

Log 
  adding: PreBook Balances Summary Sample.twb (deflated 91%)
  adding: Image/ (stored 0%)
  adding: Image/Citilogo_v2.JPG (deflated 84%)
  adding: Rate Trend Sample.twb (deflated 93%)
  adding: Image/ (stored 0%)
  adding: Image/Citilogo_v2.JPG (deflated 84%)
  adding: Tickets Summary Sample.twb (deflated 92%)
  adding: Image/ (stored 0%)
  adding: Image/Citilogo_v2.JPG (deflated 84%)
```

Comment: You set the variable `TARGET_FOLDER`, but you never use it anywhere. What is its purpose?

Comment: Sorry , it was typo, i have corrected and updated the question

Comment: I don't think that `home` will be included in the zip, at least not from the output you posted. Since you did a `cd` into `workbook`, the files will be relative to this directory. However, I wonder what the `%` in `"$file%.twb".zip` is supposed to be. You would generate a name such as `foobar.twb%.twb.zip`, and this does not make sense. My suggestion is that you run your script with `set -x` , and post the trace you will get.

Comment: This will include the Home directory in zip folder as what i have checked. What i am trying to achieve is something similar to > zip -r "test.zip" home/../../file1 home/../../file2  without the need to use cd command to go into the directory

Comment: Please show a transscript. If you cd into the directory, you won't get the abs path, unless you explicitly request ist. From the man page: _By default, zip will store the full path (relative to the current directory)_ . If you want to avoid directory names to be stored without changing into this directory, try the `--junk-paths` option of `zip`. BTW, you don't have to _hardcode_ the directory, since you have it in the variable `TABLEAU_REPORTING_FOLDER` anyway.